# undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this problem  on te line

```
<td><%= h box.manufacturer.name %></td>
```

of

```
<% @boxes.each do |box| %>
  <tr>
  <td><%= h box.manufacturer.name %></td>
  <td><%= h box.model %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Mostrar', :action => 'show', :id => box %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Editar', :action => 'edit', :id => box  %></td>
  <td><%= button_to 'Eliminar', { :action => 'destroy', :id => box },
  :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete box #{box.model}?" %></td>
```

manufacturers is a table with  field called name,its supposed that an object manufacturer has member called name ,isn it?

Comment: Show us your models, you might not have them set up correctly. If you do probably some particular box doesn't have a manufacturer.

Comment: It's quite clear one of your `box` records doesn't have its associated `manufacturer`.

Comment: BTW what version of Rails are you using?

Answer (score 4):

It's quite clear one of your `box` records doesn't have its associated `manufacturer`. If it's acceptable, you can use [`Object#try`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try) method, like this:

```
<%= box.manufacturer.try(:name) %>
```

If it's not, you should think of adding proper validation to `Box` model:

```
validates_presence_of :manufacturer
```

I didn't use `h` helper because in Rails >= 3.0 (which you probably use) untrusted content is escaped automatically.

Answer (score 2):

It means your one of your boxes doesn't have a manufacturer.

You can prevent an exception like this by using try:

```
box.try(:manufacturer).try(:name)
```

If the manufacturer doesn't exist, it will return nil instead of throwing an exception

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but in your case you seem to have a box with no manufacturer.

```
<%= h box.manufacturer.name if box.manufacturer %>
```

Or

```
<%= h box.manufacturer.try(:name) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The proposed solutions fix the issue but don't address the bug in architecture. I recommend  learning the [Tell Don't Ask](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html) principle. 
Your views shouldn't do any checks on nil as it is not their responsibility. You should always try to avoid long method chains as it will always fail on certain step.

Refactor your application like this:

**box.rb:**

```
def manufacturer_name
  manufacturer.try(:name)
end
```

**view:**

```
<td><%= h box.manufacturer_name %></td>
```

I don't think it's possible if the box is nil. If it is - then I recommend removing nils from the array before iterating over it in views like this:

**controller:**

```
@boxes = box_retrieving_method_with_nils.compact
```